# Reinstalled Vagrant and Virtualbox getting Appliance file must have .ovf extension error

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

On Windows Server 2012 R2 unininstalled and reinstalled VirtualBox and Vagrant and now with any vagrant box I get an error referring to an .ovf file.  Here is a simple example

```
C:\Users\dremy\projects\deleteme> vagrant init precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box

A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on `vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

C:\Users\dremy\projects\deleteme> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'precise32' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'precise32' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
    default: Progress: 100% (Rate: 8986k/s, Estimated time remaining:     --:--:--)
==> default: Successfully added box 'precise32' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'precise32'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "-n", "P\u2219("]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance file must have .ovf extension
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004),
    component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance, call ee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "Read(Bstr(pszAbsFilePath).raw(),
   progressRead.asOutParam())" at line 303 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Comment: note:  I tried cleaning out old boxes and using both hashicorp/precise32 and hashicorp/precise64 with the exact same results.

Comment: See the answer below but it was related to running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box having Hyper-V running.

Answer (score 0):

I think `http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box` is an old version of the box and might not be compatible with VirtualBox latest version.

New version of vagrant boxes are now hosted on https://atlas.hashicorp.com and you should be able to pick boxes from there. Following should work

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

Make sure also to clean the old box

```
vagrant box remove precise32
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I had tried that, and just tried it again with both hashicorp/precise32 and hashicorp/precise64 with the exact same results.

Comment: which version of vagrant / virtual box did you install ?

Comment: Virtualbox 5.014r105127
Vagrant 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.  I was running on Windows Server 2012 R2 and the Hyper-v role was active.  VirtualBox and Hyper-v cannot run (https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/hyperv/).  To remove Hyper-V  in PowerShell I did:

```
Remove-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V
```

Afterwards no longer had the problem.  I got the clue from this very nice article on building a windows vagrant box: http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/in-search-of-a-light-weight-windows-vagrant-box